# Handling Windows filechooser dialog with Selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, filechooser

I am wondering if there are any Selenium users who have to deal with things like the Windows File Chooser Dialog, which Selenium can't handle (and for which sendKeys() to the input box will not work)?  How do you handle the file chooser?  I have had some success eith WinAppDriver but it also causes a lot of problems with setup and building and conflicts.

In many cases we can do something like fileInput.sendKeys("filename.txt") but in this case it doesn't work and still opens a windows file dialog.

I would like to hear some options for handling these cases with Selenium (and anything else needed)?  Especially with Java.

Comment: It'll depend on the site and how it's handling things.  You may just need to send .submit() method to the input.  Or trigger some javascript that gets called after choosing a file.

Comment: I have been trying to figure out java script.  Did not try submit().  I did try javascript to set the value of the input box, but apparently security disallows that?